# I am learning react by doing a few tasks daily. This is my task but I am unsure how to proceed with it. Can anyone help me with it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Task:-

input -> take a number from user
on change -> square(number) -> square that number entered by user

Show every calculated number as a list in DOM. We need runtime display of every calculation.

If Backspace pressed- remove last computed result (list as well as input) and on every backspace we've to recalculate everything.

As soon as there is 10 computations, show alert, max 10 computation allowed.

example:-
input = 321
[9, 1024, 103041]

32
[9, 1024 ]

323
[9, 1024, 104329]

33
[9, 1089]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a codesandbox with the solution: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-flower-28t0sy)

**Brief explanation:**

- `value` is used to keep track of the user input.
- `results` is used to store the squared results, that are then displayed to the user.
- `results` is displayed using the `Array.toString()` method
- the `onChange` event in the `<input/>` field checks if the variable `input`'s length exceeds 10 or not. If it exceeds 10 then no further calculation is allowed, else it sets `value` to the new input.
- the `useEffect` hook is called each time `value` changes. Each time `value` changes, a new array of sub-strings is formed using the `String.substring()` method: Say your input was `123`, then the formed array would be `["1","12","123"]`. This array is then used to calculate and set `results`